# Render options of ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to render the options for a ModelChoiceField:

```
{% for value, label in form.fields.event_type.choices %}
    <option value="{{ value }}"
            {% if form.fields.event_type.value == value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ label }} -- {{ form.event_type.value }} .. {{ value }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not work: `selected="selected"` is not set.

The output:

```
<option value="">
  --------- -- 2 .. 
</option>

<option value="1">
  OptionOne -- 2 .. 1
</option>

<option value="2">
  OptionTwo -- 2 .. 2
</option>
```

This is strange, since the output "2 .. 2" did not trigger the "if" to include `selected`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The "if" was comparing an integer to a string, which is not equal.

This works:

```
{% for value, label in form.fields.event_type.choices %}
<option value="{{ value }}"
    {% if form.event_type.value == value|stringformat:"i" %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {{ label }} -- {{ form.event_type.value }} .. {{ value }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This solutions looks somehow too complicated. Isn't there an easier solution?